# In SQL Server 2008, when would I use a full text index that covered several tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I wanted to do a full text search across several related tables in SQL Server 2008. From browsing this site I've realised the best option is via a view, but initially I thought I was meant to add several tables to the same full text index via Management Studio. I started to do this and realised the index would have no idea how they were related, so my question is: when would I want to have a full text index covering several tables in this way?

Apologies for the vagueness, I am just trying to satisfy my curiosity after Google let me down.

Comment: Google let you down? try Bing. :D

Comment: I think you mean "Full Text Search" - a Full Text Index is just an index.  While it would condense your query, Full Text Search doesn't associate columns across tables.

Comment: Sorry, new to asking questions here and thought I would get an email to say there were comments. Thanks for the feedback.

The impression I was getting from the full text index dialogs in SQL management studio was that I could create an index featuring several tables but there seemed to be no association between them so I couldn't see how this was useful when doing a full text search.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view on multiple tables and then implement full text search on that view